# See if two nodes are cousins based on value in binary tree

Tags: c, function, binary-tree

I am trying to solve the following problem:
I must create a function which receives the tree and two numbers ( values of two different nodes) and find out if those two nodes are on the same level but they don't have the same parent.

Here is my code. Do you know how I may fix it ?

```
int level(Tree tree, int val, int lev)
{
    if(tree == NULL) return 0;
    if(tree->value == val) return lev;
    int l=level(tree->left,tree->value,lev+1);
    if(l!=0) return l;
    return level(tree->right,tree->value,lev+1);
}

int isCousin(Tree tree, int value1, int value2) {
    if((level(tree,value1,1)==level(tree,value2,1)) && !(isCousin(tree,value1,value2)))
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Here is my code. Not working, seg fault." - We are not a debugging service. Read [ask] and provide **all* required information, including a [mcve]. Note that for such homework questions, additional requirements apply. Debugging is a major part of programming, so start your debugger and become comfortable with it.

Comment: You are calling isCousin() with the same arguments that isCousin() was called with, which will recurs infinitely.

Comment: dear @Olaf, I know how to use a debugger. I asked because I could not find the solution. So, your comment is not helpful and not polite.

Comment: Ooh, this could make a good code golf question.

Comment: @Cristina so... when you ran it under your debugger, it worked?   That happens, and it's usually due to UB, eg. uninitialized vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do it is creating a function that searches for a certain value on the tree and return the depth of the element, -1 in case it doesnt exist. With that you cast that function for those 2 values, if they both return the same depth, then you know that at least those numbers exist in the tree at the same level. Having that in consideration all you need to do is reach one, you can do it in θ(log2(n)) since it's a tree and then check if its brother is the other value: if it is then they are brothers if not they are cousins.
It's not the most effective way for sure, but it is a simple solution for the problem. Hope it helps :)